# Exception while deserializing object in Debug Mode

Tags: java, debugging, serialization, netbeans

I am doing something wrong here I guess, but I can't figure out what causes the error. It's my first try at custom serialization.

I am storing objects in a database in a BLOB field. At some point I read them again.

Here is the class that is serializable:

```
public class Job extends Observable implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7530757972497270533L;

    private Path file;
    private String errorText = "";
    private int moduleID;
    private int jobID;
    private JobStatus status;

    public Job(int moduleID, Path file) {
        this.moduleID = moduleID;
        this.file = file;
        status = JobStatus.ACCEPTED;
    }

    public Path getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(Path file) {
        setChanged();
        this.file = file;
        notifyObservers(this);
    }

    public int getModuleID() {
        return moduleID;
    }

    public void setModuleID(int moduleID) {
        setChanged();
        this.moduleID = moduleID;
        notifyObservers(this);
    }

    public void setStatus(JobStatus status) {
        setChanged();
        this.status = status;
        notifyObservers(this);
    }

    public JobStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setID(int jobID) {
        this.jobID = jobID;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return jobID;
    }

    public void setErrorText(String errorText) {
        this.errorText = errorText;
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.writeUTF(file.toString());
        out.writeUTF(errorText);
        out.writeInt(moduleID);
        out.writeInt(jobID);
        out.writeInt(status.ordinal());
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        try {
            file = Paths.get(in.readUTF());
            errorText = in.readUTF();
            moduleID = in.readInt();
            jobID = in.readInt();
            status = JobStatus.values()[in.readInt()];
        } catch (Exception e) { //just for debugging purposes
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "moduleID=" + moduleID + ", jobID=" + jobID;
    }

}
```

For reasons of simplification mentioned in the comments here is the additional code on how to test it without the use of a database:

```
public enum JobStatus {

    ACCEPTED, PROCESSING, FINISHED, ERROR
}
```

---

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Job job = new Job(1, Paths.get("C:/temp"));
            Job job2 = deepCopy(job);
            System.out.println(job2.getFile());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static Job deepCopy(Job job) throws Exception {
        // Serialization of object
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        out.writeObject(job);

        // De-serialization of object
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        Job copied = (Job) in.readObject();

        return copied;
    }

}
```

Now if I just let the program run everything seems fine. The `Job` gets created and I can work with it. But at some point I wanted to debug the `readObject()` method in `Job`. Only in debug mode (in Netbeans) this method throws Exceptions like the following:

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(ObjectInputStream.java:2823)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readInt(ObjectInputStream.java:972)
    at test.Job.readObject(Job.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1896)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at test.Test.deepCopy(Test.java:40)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:23)
```

This exception is thrown in the `readObject()` method. If I click very fast I can reach one of the `writeInt()` methods but then I get an `EOFException`. Does something manipulate my `ObjectInputStream`?

I cannot reproduce the same error with the exact same code in Eclipse.

Can anybody tell me what's going wrong here?

Comment: Hint: can you avoid the "database" part? What I mean: have you tried to simply serizalize/desiralize in memory? You see, there is no need to make the task at hand (custom serialization) more complex to debug ... by immediately combining it with "use data base".

Comment: maybe try converting your BLOB data to TEXT with utf-8 encoding before reading? [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,164923,167648#msg-167648) is something that might help with that if you want.

Comment: @Jägermeister I edited the question. It's also happening  in the simplified example but less often (only like every fifth time).

Comment: Check JRE and compilance level used for Eclipse and NetBeans, also check source file encoding in both.

Comment: I can only find text file encoding in eclipse. that is set to "Default (Cp1252)". There's no encoding specified in the netbeans.conf. Runtime is jdk1.8.0_45 on both IDEs. Compliance level is 1.8 on both.

Comment: do you see any other db errors, may be db is closing the stream on you

Comment: @KalpeshSoni in the example i posted i left out the db. It happens with in memory serialization, too.

Comment: I confirm it is not happening in Normal or Debug mode under Eclipse Mars using JDK 1.8_45. Maybe this is a bug on Netbeans and should be reported for further investigation in https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/

Comment: Add long `sleep`s between each operation and see if the error appears without debugging too

Comment: for some reason (maybe just a reboot) this problem cannot be reproduced anmyore